# How to mock nested object methods in Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, stripe-payments

I am not 100% sure my terminology is right here, but what I want to do is as follows.
I managed to successfully mock stripe.customers.create by creating a manual mock like this:

```
__mocks__/stripe.js 

class Stripe {}
const stripe = jest.fn(() => new Stripe()); 
module.exports = stripe;
module.exports.Stripe = Stripe;
```

then in my unit.test.js I import the mock like this

```
const { Stripe } = require("stripe");
Stripe.prototype.customers = {
  create: jest.fn(() => {
    return {
      id: "cus_testid",
    };
  }),
};
```

And the stripe.customers.create() method is mocked just fine. However, the problem starts when I start to (for the lack of better word) "nest" or "chain" the methods further down the stripe object. For example this mock will not work:

```
Stripe.prototype.checkout.sessions = {
  create: jest.fn(() => {
    return {
      session: {
        url: 'someurl'
      }
    }
  })
}
```

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'sessions' of undefined

Why can't I set up such a nested method mock and how should I approach doing such a nested mock? Should I modify the manual mock to accomplish this?

Comment: How did you use the mocked stripe api?

Comment: If you mean the original implementation, where the Stripe API is being mocked, then like this (I am using billingPortal instead of checkout, because of shorter syntax): 
const portalSession = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
   customer: stripeCustomerId, 
   return_url: returnUrl,
 });

Answer (score -1):

According to the [doc](https://site-admin.stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=node), the `url` is an immediate property to the Session object, so you should just return `{url: 'someUrl' }` instead of wrapping it inside another `session` property.

By the way, you might also be interested in [stripe-mock](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-mock), It's a mock HTTP server that responds like the real Stripe API.

Comment: But the break point in here is this: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'sessions' of undefined", i.e. JS saying that "Stripe.prototype.checkout" is undefined.